# AVPlayerviewcontroller Voice Over Accessibility

Tags: ios, avplayer, tvos, voiceover, avplayerviewcontroller

I am using default AVPlayerviewcontroller for video streaming in my tvOS app and no custom player controls are used. Can we override the AVPlayerviewcontroller voice over accessibility text/behaviour in the playerviewcontroller for the default player controls? I am not to find out any API in apple's documentation site on this.